# Minus in Hibernate query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, one-to-many

I want to achieve a query, which selects all the parent with only children who fill this condition *children.date = today*. The goal is increase performance, i don't need children of other days.

```
Query q = ss.createQuery("select p from Parent p where exists( from p.children c where    c.date = :now)");
     q.setTimestamp("now", new DateTime().minusDays(1).toDate());
     qc=q.list();
```

Another way :

```
DateMidnight first = new DateMidnight(); //today at 00h00 00min 00 JodaTime
  ss.createCriteria(Parent.class)
      .createAlias("children", "c")
      .add(Restrictions.between("c.date",first.toDate(), first.plus(14400000).toDate()))
      .list();
```

**Parent Class**

```
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany( cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy = "parentId",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Column(name="id_parent",nullable=true,unique = true)
  @Cascade(value={org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE,org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.REMOVE})
  private List<Child> children=new ArrayList<Child>();
```

and the Child.class

```
@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
 @Column(name = "childID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long childId1;

private Date date;

private String childId2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If that field is a Timestamp date and time, change your query so that you query all data between (date 00:00:00 and date 23:59:59) that should give you all data you want

Comment: What does toDate()? If your column is a timestamp (date + TIME) then your problem might be the call toDate() which looks like it returns a date and not a timestamp.

Comment: I'm using PostGreSQL, and column is a timestamp, but ti's worked with date. But i don't get what i'm lookin for yet

Comment: I think it's working beacause converting a date to a timestamp results in a date with time 00:00:00.000. So the query is working but your result is not what you expect. If your datatype is datetime then you have to use a datetime type and not a date type.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use a HQL named query with Hibernate filters.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html

Parent code will become something like this:

```
  @OneToMany( cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy = "parentId",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  [...]
  @Filter(name = "todayChildrenOnly", condition = "date = :now")
  private List<Child> children=new ArrayList<Child>();
```

The above will be translated in a SQL join condition as well as the foreign key check (join ... on ...).
If "date" is an index of child table, you should get better performances.